# undefined variable in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Below is the my ansible tasks which will fetch domain name and which will register the output to item value so that i can use the variable across my playbook.

```
- name: Fetching the domain name
  shell: dnsdomainname | cut -d "." -f 1
  register: domain_name

- debug: 
     msg: "DC detected {{domain_name}}"
  when: domain_name.stdout == item.key
  with_dict: {abc: 01, cde: 05}
  register: number == item.value
```

But it was throwing the error as below:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'number' is undefined\n\n
```

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: it's better you append the new edit after the original, otherwise, the answers will seems wield as your question entirely changed

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the you are looping using `with_dict: {abc: 08, cde: 04}` and registering into `server_path`. In this case `server_path` will contain a results array that will wrap all the
output of the calls to `stat`. You can verify this by debugging the `server_path` variable.

```
- debug: msg="{{server_path}}"
```

You need to access the result via an array index. Example: `server_path.results[0].stat.isdir`

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
when: domain_name == item.key
```

**EDIT**

change `domain_name` to `domain_name.stdout` and test `server_path.stat is defined` first.

```
- name: Checking for webpage path
  stat: path=/etc/apps/dc{{item.value}}/webpage.html
  when: domain_name.stdout == item.key
  with_dict: {abc: 08, cde: 04}
  register: server_path

- debug: msg="server path exists"
  when: server_path.stat is defined and server_path.stat.isdir is defined and server_path.stat.isdir
```

Comment: previous is `domain_name == {{ item.key }}`, OP has edited it

Comment: Thank you - sel-fish ... But i still couldn't able to overcome the error that i posted which is "dict object' has no attribute 'stat'\n\n" . Even the server path exists , it is still throwing the same error.

Comment: @kenny did you change `domain_name` to `domain_name.stdout` in the task `Checking for webpage path` ?

Comment: It worked . but after changing the playbook logic it is not working.